# JQuery ResponsiveSlides Image Slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-slides

Okay so I'm tring to implement a responsive slides element in to my page. However, nothing I seem to do works. First I noticed that in order for the css code to be applied it had to be accessed using ul.name. Now for some reason, the .js file doesn't seem to work at all because none of the images show? The alt name field show and transitions with the names work but there are no images. Any help is appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Accessorize With Style</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="responsiveslides.js"></script>
<link href="responsiveslides.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("ul.rslides").responsiveSlides();
  });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
}

/* ~~ Element/tag selectors ~~ */
ul, ol, dl { /* Due to variations between browsers, it's best practices to zero padding and margin on lists. For consistency, you can either specify the amounts you want here, or on the list items (LI, DT, DD) they contain. Remember that what you do here will cascade to the .nav list unless you write a more specific selector. */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    margin-top: 0;   /* removing the top margin gets around an issue where margins can escape from their containing div. The remaining bottom margin will hold it away from any elements that follow. */
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px; /* adding the padding to the sides of the elements within the divs, instead of the divs themselves, gets rid of any box model math. A nested div with side padding can also be used as an alternate method. */
}
a img { /* this selector removes the default blue border displayed in some browsers around an image when it is surrounded by a link */
    border: none;
}

/* ~~ Styling for your site's links must remain in this order - including the group of selectors that create the hover effect. ~~ */
a:link {
    color:#414958;
    text-decoration: underline; /* unless you style your links to look extremely unique, it's best to provide underlines for quick visual identification */
}
a:visited {
    color: #4E5869;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus { /* this group of selectors will give a keyboard navigator the same hover experience as the person using a mouse. */
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* ~~ this container surrounds all other divs giving them their percentage-based width ~~ */
.container {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1260px;/* a max-width may be desirable to keep this layout from getting too wide on a large monitor. This keeps line length more readable. IE6 does not respect this declaration. */
    min-width: 780px;/* a min-width may be desirable to keep this layout from getting too narrow. This keeps line length more readable in the side columns. IE6 does not respect this declaration. */
    margin: 0 auto; /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout. It is not needed if you set the .container's width to 100%. */
    overflow: hidden; /* this declaration makes the .container clear all floated columns within it. */
}
.logo img {
    width:auto\9;
    max-width:100%;
}
.sidebar1 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    height:100%;
}
.content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}
.sidebar2 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

/* ~~ This grouped selector gives the lists in the .content area space ~~ */
.content ul, .content ol { 
    padding: 0 15px 15px 40px; /* this padding mirrors the right padding in the headings and paragraph rule above. Padding was placed on the bottom for space between other elements on the lists and on the left to create the indention. These may be adjusted as you wish. */
}

/* ~~ The navigation list styles (can be removed if you choose to use a premade flyout menu like Spry) ~~ */
ul.nav {
    list-style: none; /* this removes the list marker */
    border-top: 1px solid #666; /* this creates the top border for the links - all others are placed using a bottom border on the LI */
    margin-bottom: 15px; /* this creates the space between the navigation on the content below */
}
ul.nav li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666; /* this creates the button separation */
}
ul.nav a, ul.nav a:visited { /* grouping these selectors makes sure that your links retain their button look even after being visited */
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
    display: block; /* this gives the link block properties causing it to fill the whole LI containing it. This causes the entire area to react to a mouse click. */
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #8090AB;
    color: #000;
}
ul.nav a:hover, ul.nav a:active, ul.nav a:focus { /* this changes the background and text color for both mouse and keyboard navigators */
    background: #6F7D94;
    color: #FFF;
}

/* ~~ miscellaneous float/clear classes ~~ */
.fltrt {  /* this class can be used to float an element right in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
    float: right;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.fltlft { /* this class can be used to float an element left in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.clearfloat { /* this class can be placed on a <br /> or empty div as the final element following the last floated div (within the #container) if the overflow:hidden on the .container is removed */
    clear:both;
    height:0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
-->
</style><!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style>
.content { margin-right: -1px; } /* this 1px negative margin can be placed on any of the columns in this layout with the same corrective effect. */
ul.nav a { zoom: 1; }  /* the zoom property gives IE the hasLayout trigger it needs to correct extra whiltespace between the links */
</style>
<![endif]--></head>

<body background="images/background.jpg">

<div class="container">
<div class="logo">
<center><img src="images/logo.png"></center>
</div>
  <div class="sidebar1">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Necklaces</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bracelets</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Earings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Rings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Scarves</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bracelets</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- end .sidebar1 --></div>
  <div class="content">
<ul class="rslides">
<li><img src="images/gallery/bracelet.jpg" alt="bracelet" /></li>
<li><img src="images/gallery/earings.jpg" alt="earings" /></li>
<li><img src="images/gallery/necklace.jpg" alt="necklaces" /></li>
<li><img src="images/gallery/ring.jpg" alt="ring" /></li>
<li><img src="images/gallery/scarves.jpg" alt="scarves" /></li> 
</ul>
</div>
  <div class="sidebar2">
    <h4>Backgrounds</h4>
    <p>By nature, the background color on any div will only show for the length of the content. If you'd like a dividing line instead of a color, place a border on the side of the .content div (but only if it will always contain more content).</p>
    <!-- end .sidebar2 --></div>
  <!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why is there a `-->` located in your styles? (ps. you should stick your css in an external css file.)

Comment: @SridharR, I'm not getting any error, it just doesn't work

Comment: @Kristof Feys, that was auto generated by dreamweaver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for me this is just working. http://jsfiddle.net/9Zuj6/ (note that the images are not shown because these are not in the directory, but you do see the sliding effect).
one solution might be to put your

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("ul.rslides").responsiveSlides();
  });
</script>
```

right before your `</body>` tag.
i would also change it to:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.rslides").responsiveSlides();
  });
</script>
```

and you should also remove the
`-->` and `<!--` tags between your `<style>` tags.

Comment: Thanks for the response, okay so I tried doing what you suggested and many others. I got the pictures to show but no change is making the images switch.

Comment: Ok, I copied and pasted the working jfiddle, uploaded and it still doesn't work. Therefore that leads me to believe ti can't find the jquery or the slider files.

Comment: I made the site live in a back end. See it here, www.accessorizewithstylenj.com/index3.html

Comment: the url you shared doesn't exist

Comment: Correct it doesn't anymore. I actually just figure it out. What the problem was, I was calling responsiveslides.js when it wanted responsiveslides.min.js. The new url is www.accessorizewithstylenj.com